# Resulting in an `error: incomplete type` while using std::tuple_size

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a class template in a namespace
And I have a non member function inside that namespace which returns a `std::tuple` of `std::shared_ptr(s)<myown::myclass<Type>>`
I invoked the function `F()` and passed its result(`std::tuple`) to an another non-member function(inside `myown` namespace)

```
namespace myown {

    template<typename T> class myclass{ /*...*/};

    template<>           class myclass<void>{ /*...*/};

    auto F()
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::shared_ptr<myclass<int>>(),
                               std::shared_ptr<myclass<const char *>>(),
                               std::shared_ptr<myclass<int>>());
    }

    template <typename tup>
    auto anotherF(tup&& result){
        size_t s = std::tuple_size<tup>::value;//
        /*...*/
    }
}

 int main()
 {
     auto tr = myown::F();
     myown::anotherF(tr);
 }
```

Use of `std::tuple_size<tup>` results in `error: incomplete type...used in nested name specifier`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to decay the type to remove reference:

```
size_t s = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<tup>>::value;
```

Comment: Thanks I really didn't think about decaying the tuple type,To me the error was somewhat misleading may be because I've never dealt with'em :)

Comment: @Explorer_N: If you read carefully the error (that you skip in question :/) *"error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::tuple_size<std::tuple<...> &>'"*, you can see the problematic reference near the end.